# Core Data and User-Defined Attributes

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I have an application that is ultimately a database program. Currently, I am using an NSMutableArray of "element" objects which have a couple dozen pre-defined properties and one property which is a mutable dictionary that is used for user-defined properties (which are defined at run-time).

To do this I use `valueForUndefinedKey:` which causes a lookup in the "user fields" mutable dictionary. It all works very well and allows me to build predicates based on both built-in properties as well as user-defined properties.

I am considering moving it to Core Data but can't determine a way to allow the user to define properties (attributes in Core Data-speak). I can create a transformable attribute that is a dictionary which the user could add keys/values to, but there is no way to search it.

I also thought that my built-in properties/attributes could be done in Core Data and then a separate non-Core Data array could hold dictionaries for my user-defined fields (basically the same way it does now). Will this work well?

I have an NSTableView that has to show columns from both built-in fields as well as user-defined fields (using bindings) and I need to be able to build Predicates that encompass both types too.

So for example my elements are "Person" and the built-in attributes are Name, Birthday, Phone Number, etc and then the user can add fields to these such as "Make, Model, Credit Score", etc.

I am not certain that Core Data is a good fit for this when my app has to allow the creation of user-defined fields/properties/attributes, while still keeping them searchable with user-built predicates.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered defining a entity to store User-Defined key/value pairs? Something like:

[image]

This would allow you continue to use predicates to query your data, for instance:

```swift
let request = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userDefined.key == %@", "somekey")
```

Or queries based on value or data type:

```swift
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userDefined.value == %@", "somevalue")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userDefined.dataType == %@", "String")
```

You could continue to use a transformable type on `UserDefined.value` or a binary type, using the `dataType` as a hint to how to transform/decode the data.

Comment: This looks promising. My keys would be UUIDs (basically a field identifier) and values would mostly be strings so I would need a predicate that could be something like:`userDefined.key == someUUID AND userDefined.value == userTextEntry` Whereas right now with NSArray I can set up the left side of my NSPredicateEditor with the UUID, some comparison operator and the right side with a user string.

I'm trying to think about how to fit the above methodology into an `NSPredicateEditor` so the left side could still be a menu with birthday, name, phone and the English names of my keys.

Comment: The other issue is that I need to ensure that a Person can't have multiple UserDefined records with the same key.

Comment: One more thought on this method: in an NSTableView it is easy to show the value of name or phone in a column, but how would I show (in a column) the userDefined value for a given key for a given Person (assuming each Person gets a row in the table)?

Comment: As far as using NSPredicateEditor, is there a reason you can't use the 'english names' for your keys? What's the reason of introducing a UUID to the situation? You'll have to write code to check/disallow writing a duplicate keys. You won't be able to use bindings directly to the 'UserDefined' value. Maybe write an accessor on your 'Person' to access the top user-defined fields, and bind to those?

Comment: The UUID just ensures uniqueness. An accessor would have to take a key as an argument and do the lookup among the UserDefined objects. Not sure if I could bind like that? I guess I could use valueForUndefinedKey: like I do now and just bind to the undefined key which would then be looked up. This seems like it might be an order of magnitude slower than the straight array lookup using this technique in my current implementation.

Comment: I can't really see a way to make this work so that the values of the user-defined fields can be displayed in an NSTableView. The only (ugly) solution I can think of is to limit the number of user-defined fields to 20 or so, and then define properties `userdefined01, userdefined02...`